# Solution to "Error 000918: Cannot retrieve feature class extent"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I have an ArcGIS model where I merge two multipoint feature classes, Then I would like to use "Point to Raster" on it. Cell extent is specified through the input DEM which all data derives from. It worked many times, but now after changing the storage location of an intermediate result right before the "Point to Raster" tool, I get the error message "Error 000918: Cannot retrieve feature class extent". What does that mean? I didn't change the input data, but the model doesn't work anymore.

System: Win7, ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced 10.2.1, 3D and Spatial Analyst.

edit: When I run the model to this point (Zusammenführen/Merge (2)) as shown below, the problem does not occur anymore. Why is it not possible to run the whole model at once?

See the specified part of the model below:
[image]

Comment: You say _"...changing the storage location of an intermediate result right before the "Point to Raster" tool..."_. Is this the Heckenverlauf_Buffer_Buffer_2? Please tell us what the location is. Also have you changed any environment settings? Maybe they are persisting and are now not appropriate?

Comment: I have several geodatabases in my central directory C:\Users\...\Documents\Projektarbeit_6. I use one as scratch workspace and another to store the results. With older storage settings my model worked but now after changing the storage location to the other gdb it doesn't work anymore.