# arcpy PolygonToRaster ERROR 000918: Cannot retrieve feature class extent

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to convert a polygon feature class (created intermediately as part of a larger process) to a raster, which will have the same snap settings and cell size as another input raster.  However, every time i try to run it, I get this error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000918: Cannot retrieve feature class extent.
```

I cannot find any help on this issue and I don't know what to do.  I have already seen [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120241/solution-to-error-000918-cannot-retrieve-feature-class-extent) question and it did not help resolve the issue.

This is the code:

```
cell_size = float(GetRasterProperties(in_raster, 'CELLSIZEX').getOutput(0))

env.snapRaster = in_raster

PolygonToRaster(buffer_fc, z_field_name, stamp_raster, cellsize=cell_size)

return None
```

The same parameters work when I execute "Polygon To Raster" diretly from the ArcToolbox GUI.

Comment: Is it possible that your feature class is being locked by a prior process?

Comment: It's the output of MultipleRingBuffer.  Is there a way for me to check if it's being locked directly? EDIT: Yes it seems that it is being locked, because arcpy.TestSchemaLock(fc) is returning "1"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to MaryBeth for suggesting that it was a schema lock issue.  By running `arcpy.TestSchemaLock()` on the feature class that I was trying to convert to raster (`buffer_fc`), I saw that it was being locked, which was preventing `PolygonToRaster()` from acquiring its extent and therefore failing.  Apparently, `MultipleRingBuffer()` has some locking issues (that was where `buffer_fc` came from).  I used `arcpy.CopyFeatures()` to copy it to a new dataset and then ran `PolygonToRaster()` on that instead, and it worked perfectly.